# How to include current date in mongodb-haskell aggregation query

Tags: mongodb, haskell, aggregation-framework

I'm using the MongoDB Haskell package (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mongoDB) and trying to write an aggregation query which make use of the current date. I can do that with Haskell's getCurrentTime, but it should also be possible to let MongoDB use the current date directly.

It seems like the only way to include a field with BSON type Date is using the Haskell UTC constructor and pass a UTCTime from haskell.

Is there not a way to get something similar to the following to work?

```
getNotes :: Action IO [Document]
getNotes = aggregate "delivery_notes"
  [ "$match" =: [ "delivery_date" =: [ "$lte" =:  "$currentDate" ]
                , "delivery_date" =: [ "$lte" =: (Javascript [] "new Date()")]
                ]
  ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing in pure JS it is possible to include a `new Date()` statement directly in query, but using the Haskell `mongoDB` library I ended up including `getCurrentTime` from the `time` library.

```
getNotes :: Action IO [Document]
getNotes = do
  t <- liftIO $ getCurrentTime
  aggregate "delivery_notes"
    [ "$match" =: [ "delivery_date" =: [ "$lte" =:  "$currentDate" ]
    , "delivery_date" =: [ "$lte" =: String (formatDateTime t)]
                         ]
    ]

formatDateTime :: UTCTime -> Text
formatDateTime = tshow . formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%F %R"
```